# Magento Admin section - Rewrite custom options in products edit displays blank content

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2. I created a custom module for the admin section for rewriting the Custom options tab in the product edit section

`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option`

My config file

`config.xml`

```
 <global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product_edit_tab_options>
                    Mymodule_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option
                </catalog_product_edit_tab_options>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

My class file

`Mymodule\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option.php`

```
class Mymodule_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option
{

    /**
     * Class constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo "Here";
    }

}
```

The block is rewriting but its displaying blank content. I set the MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE and ther are no errors displaying in the page.

Can anyone point out what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue

It was the space between the `<catalog_product_edit_tab_options>` tag which was creating the problem. I changed

```
<catalog_product_edit_tab_options>
Mymodule_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option
</catalog_product_edit_tab_options>
```

to

```
 <catalog_product_edit_tab_options>Mymodule_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option</catalog_product_edit_tab_options>
```

in the config.xml. An error if displayed would have saved me lots of time.